# Does $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\tfrac{\binom{2k}{k}}{2^{2k}} (1-x)^{2k} (\sum_{l=0}^k \tfrac{(c \tfrac{x}{\sqrt{(1-x)}})^{2l} (k)_l}{(2l)!})^2 )$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose $c \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Does  $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\tfrac{\binom{2k}{k}}{2^{2k}} (1-x)^{2k} \left( \sum_{l=0}^k \tfrac{\left(c \tfrac{x}{\sqrt{(1-x)}}\right)^{2l} (k)_l}{(2l)!} \right)^2 \right)$$
converge for all $0<x<1$?

$(k)_l$ is meant to be the falling factorial.

Since $2\cdot 4^{k-1} >\binom{2k}{k} >2\cdot 3^{k-1}$ for $k \ge 1$ the convergence largely depends on how fast the finite sum increases.

That sum looks a bit like $\cosh$ and for large $k$ the estimation $$\cosh \left(c \tfrac{x}{\sqrt{(1-x)}}\right) \le \sum_{l=0}^k \tfrac{\left(c \tfrac{x}{\sqrt{(1-x)}}\right)^{2l} (k)_l}{(2l)!} \le  \cosh \left(\sqrt{k}c \tfrac{x}{\sqrt{(1-x)}}\right)$$ should hold. Not sure where I should go from there, though.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.